# Difference between JSoup Element and JSoup Node

Tags: java, jsoup

Can anyone please explain the difference between the `Element` object and `Node` object provided in JSoup ?

Which is the best thing to be used in which situation/condition.

Answer (score 10):

A node is the generic name for any type of object in the DOM hierarchy.

An element is one specific type of node.

The JSoup class model reflects this:

- [Node](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html)
- [Element](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)

Since `Element extends Node` anything you can do on a `Node`, you can do on an `Element` too. But `Element` provides additional behaviour which makes it easier to use, for example; an `Element` has properties such as `id` and `class` etc which make it easier to find them in a HTML document.

In most cases using `Element` (or one of the other subclasses of `Document`) will meet your needs and will be *easier* to code to. I suspect the only scenario in which you might need to fall back to `Node` is if there is a specific node type in the DOM for which JSoup does not provide a subclass of `Node`.

Here's an example showing the same HTML document inspection using both `Node` and `Element`:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>This is the head</title></head><body><p>This is the body</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Node root = doc.root();

// some content assertions, using Node
assertThat(root.childNodes().size(), is(1));
assertThat(root.childNode(0).childNodes().size(), is(2));
assertThat(root.childNode(0).childNode(0), instanceOf(Element.class));
assertThat(((Element)  root.childNode(0).childNode(0)).text(), is("This is the head"));
assertThat(root.childNode(0).childNode(1), instanceOf(Element.class));
assertThat(((Element)  root.childNode(0).childNode(1)).text(), is("This is the body"));

// the same content assertions, using Element
Elements head = doc.getElementsByTag("head");
assertThat(head.size(), is(1));
assertThat(head.first().text(), is("This is the head"));
Elements body = doc.getElementsByTag("body");
assertThat(body.size(), is(1));
assertThat(body.first().text(), is("This is the body"));
```

YMMV but I think the `Element` form is easier to use and much less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

It's seem like same. but different.

Node have Element. and additionally have TextNode too.

so... Example.

```
<p>A<span>B</span></p>
```

In P Elements.

```
.childNodes() // get node list
-> A
-> <span>B</span>

.children() // get element list
-> <span>B</span>
```